# Can I get around Bento's Database Password?

Tags: password, bento

**Bento** is being discontinued so I want to get my data out and export it to Filemaker using one of the tools that converts the data properly, including images, popup menus, etc.
Unfortunately, at some point, I established a **Database Password** in the Preferences>Security settings but now, despite all my PW redundancies the PW I have on file does not work. 
Bento says you're screwed if you lose your PW but I'm hoping against hope that someone knows a way to crack this. I've (foolishly) invested a lot of time into these Bento records and the thought of starting from scratch is depressing me. THANKS!

Comment: Try the password you think you set, but with caps lock on - nothing specific to Bento, just to ways passwords can be not what you wrote down.

Answer (score 1):

**No, there's currently no way to obtain the password if you've forgotten it.**
What'd be the purpose of an encrypting password if you could bypass it? ;)

> After creating a password, click on the "Set Password" button to confirm.  Please note that passwords are case sensitive, and that **lost or forgotten passwords cannot be recovered.**

<sup>Source: [http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7340/~/passwords-and-encrypted-fields](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7340/%7E/passwords-and-encrypted-fields)</sup>

> The only way to eradicate a database password is to navigate to the security preferences, and uncheck the "Use Database Password" option. Of course, you must know the password in order to remove the password. There is no way to recover a password or remove it if it is forgotten. This is why Bento presents a user with this warning once a password has been set:
>
> [image: Important! If you forget your Database Password, it is not possible to recover it. Store your Database Password in a safe place.]

<sup>Source: http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/62e53480b4</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I know how silly my request sounds, given the instructions but i asked out of desperation. Thought it wouldn't hurt to try.